# Mysql Trigger for updating table involving multiple table

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-update

I have 2 table `doc` and `link` with following structures.

`doc` - `did`|`inlink`|`inlinkvalue`|`outlink`|`outlinkvalue`|`pagerank`

`link` - `did`|`linkto` Both `did` and `linkto` has Foreign key to `doc.did`

I am trying to create a `TRIGGER` where by when links are added to `link` table then `inlink`,`inlinkval` and `outlink`gets updated automatically in `doc` table.

While I am able to update the `inlink` and `outlink` count by the below `TRIGGER`, am unable to make sql query for `inlinkval`. The `inlinkval` value is `SUM` of all `outlinkvalue` of all documents(`did`) which links to this document. My present TRIGGER is

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
TRIGGER T_after_link AFTER INSERT 
ON link 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
UPDATE doc SET outlink=outlink+1 WHERE doc.did=NEW.did;
UPDATE doc SET inlink=inlink+1 WHERE doc.did=NEW.linkto;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the sum of outlinkvalue for all those dids those linkto equals with the linkto being inserted:

```
select sum(outlinkvalue) from link inner join doc on link.did=doc.did where link.linkto=NEW.linkto;
```

Place the above query in an update:

```
update doc set inlinkvalue=(select outlinksum from (select sum(outlinkvalue) as outlinksum from link inner join doc on link.did=doc.did where link.linkto=NEW.linkto) t)
```

I used the extra subquery because mysql is fussy about selecting from a table that is being updated.

Comment: I think I am doing it wrong ! Moving `inlnkvalue` into another table will ease this operation.

Comment: You could change the approach and instead of using sum() just add the outlinkvalue of the newly linked document to the inlinkvalue.